# Is it possible to describe a remote javascript as a typescript module with .d.ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm was trying to describe a remote javascript as a typescript module with a `.d.ts` file but I got an error message

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'player' in
>   '/Users/iepsen/project/src'.

It happens because it trying to load a local module.

So how can I load a remote javascript and let typescript know their methods and param types?

src/types/globals.d.ts

```
declare module 'player' {
    namespace player {
        function constructor(param1: string, param2: string): void
        function play(): void
    }
    export = player
}
```

src/index.tsx

```
import * as Player from 'player';
Player.play();
```

Comment: What do you mean remote javascript?  
The typedef usually needs to be next to the file, which is not the case on remote scripts

Comment: I meaning a CDN hosted javascript file, to be loaded from http protocol.

Comment: @MarceloIepsen then you need instruct your loader to map the module specifier `'player'` to the CDN url. This is a runtime error, not a TypeScript error.

Comment: @AluanHaddad how can I map a module to CDN?

Comment: @MarceloIepsen it depends on the loader you use. For example, in SystemJS you can add it to your `SystemJS.config` under `map`. Refer to the documentation for whichever tool you use (e.g. SystemJS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this `player` module isn't something actually included with your code when you build, you will need to declare it and use it as an Ambient Namespace.

See the last paragraph in [Typescript's Namespaces documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) for their description of Ambient Namespaces.

In essence, you need to modify your `.d.ts` file to:

```
declare namespace Player {
    export interface Base {
        function constructor(param1: string, param2: string): void;
        function play(): void;
    }
}

declare var Player: Player.Base;
```

and then in your `index.tsx`

```
// No need for import, as it's an ambient module
Player.play();
```

Comment: Note: I am somewhat assuming that by a "remote", "CDN hosted" file you mean that it stands on its own and declares some global javascript varaibles for you to use.

Comment: Your conflating ambient and global. They are not the same.